# Port forward in Aws EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, port

Am running nodejs /expressjs on aws ec2 instance. And all my ports are working correctly, I could access the port 3000 from my local postman ! But, while on local development i have used ngrok in order to forward 3000 to its unique URL.

But, in ec2 scenario, i can access the api end points only by using url.com:3000/api but how to use only public dns for ex - awsec2.com/api in instead of using awsec2.com:3000/api ? How to redirect or forward what ever to port 3000

I dont know where to start, so havent tried anything:

```
Jist:

How to convert ec2 instance to directly listen 3000,

so that i can use "awsec2.com/api" instead of "awsec2.com:3000/api"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`http://awsec2.com/api` is equivalent to  `http://awsec2.com:80/api`

`https://awsec2.com/api` is equivalent to  `https://awsec2.com:443/api`

So, you simply need to listen to port 80 and 443 and forward it to 3000.

Forwarding 80 to 3000

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3000
```

Comment: ya how to forward it ?